# jquery query builer json to java issue

Tags: java, mysql, json, elasticsearch

i jsut want to create a query builder so for that i use Jquery Query builder that gives me a json please help me to know what next i can to with that json to execute my query,for this i  do google that shows me to use elasticsearch  API but i unable to find end to end tutorial of elastic search please help me to done this i have three tables on which i want to create query builder. i have json like

```
{
    "condition": "AND",
    "rules": [{
        "id": "BirthDate",
        "field": "BirthDate",
        "type": "date",
        "input": "text",
        "operator": "equal",
        "value": "2016/04/12"
    }, {
        "id": "tumorType",
        "field": "tumorType",
        "type": "integer",
        "input": "select",
        "operator": "not_equal",
        "value": "malignant"
    }, {
        "id": "pStage",
        "field": "pStage",
        "type": "integer",
        "input": "select",
        "operator": "in",
        "value": "IB2"
    }]
}
```

in that birth date is from one table tumor type is from another table pstage is from another please tell me how i have to use this json in java to get data from mysql.in my application we use JPA. please help

Comment: what you did already? show your code

Comment: i don't know what to do next how to use this json to create query please help me to know what i need to do next...